# WPF Image scroller - looking for a control that behaves like in the image

Tags: wpf

In WPF, What is the best way to implement a control like in the picture below ? 
you have many images, not all of them can be seen at once but you can do some paging to the right and to the left, or scrolling , I'm not sure how to call it.
the two buttons in the sides scroll right and left and brings new images.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you require scrolling of images you can use a simple ListBox (you can make it horizontal if you would like to), and if you bind the listbox to an ItemsSource of images apply an ItemTemplate that will contain images.

Here's an example for an horizontal ListBox -

http://immersivenick.wordpress.com/2012/01/14/wpf-short-horizontal-listbox/

If you do not use binding you can just add LisBoxItems with image content.

Comment: Thanks Orchestrator, what about the two buttons in the sides that should do the scrolling ?

Comment: I've done this in the past but at the moment I don't have the code with me. If I recall correctly, you can expose the ListBox's ScrollViewer and then set its Horizontal/Vertical Offset

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have it a bit more appealing you can use a Carousel Control.

There are some free ones around:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/181835/WPF-Carousel-Control

And some commercial ones.
I have used the Infragistics Carousel Control and find it quite good:
http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/wpf/xamcarouselpanel.aspx#Overview