# WPF Image Carousal Control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, carousel

In my WPF app I have many images of books which i want to display in an Image Carousel/Slider control.

In that control, when i click on right arrow (pic) new set of 4 images will come out in a smooth way.

Is there any free one out there.

[image]

This kind of tech is included in our website using javascript and stuff but i want a WPF one.

Comment: You must not have searched very hard, there are hundreds of suitable results, some of which link back to SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409256/wpf-image-scroller-looking-for-a-control-that-behaves-like-in-the-image

Comment: @Duane: I got that one also. But as i said its not a solid one.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: How do you define "solid?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/181835/WPF-Carousel-Control

http://fluidkit.codeplex.com/

http://blog.pixelingene.com/2007/06/the-elementflow-custom-control-can-do-coverflow-too/

Answer (score 2):

For a carousel control I know of [FluidKit](http://fluidkit.codeplex.com/). it's only available in source-only form under a [BSD license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses) according to the [introductory blog](http://blog.pixelingene.com/2008/03/introducing-fluidkit-a-wpf-library-of-controls-helpers-and-the-likes/). in particular, have a look at the [ElementFlow](http://blog.pixelingene.com/2008/03/elementflow-added-to-fluidkit/) control.

[image]